# Redirecting light using light

Tags: electromagnetism, physical-chemistry

I was wondering if it were possible to have some chemical that would change it's state for some duration when hit by a beam of some frequency of light, such that it would change from transparent to reflective/refractive to another beam of light along the same axis of a different frequency, in a way to change the 2nd beam's trajectory?  Does something like this already exist?  If not, has it been theorised?

```
                                    ^
                                   // Altered trajectory
                                  //
  >>beam2>> >>beam1>>     **chemical compound**
```

The idea is to have a *uniform* substrate of this compound, where you fire beam1 to saturate a line in it.  Once saturated, beam1 would shut off and the line would start to revert, but in section order in which they were transformed.

```
t0     >>beam1>> [section 0][section 2]...[section n]

tn     >>beam1>> [SECTION 0][SECTION 2]...[SECTION n]
```

Beam2 would pulse, emitting light along the length of the line, but only at sections that haven't been reverted.

```
                     //
tn+0   >>beam2>> [SECTION 0][SECTION 2]...[SECTION n]

tn+2             [section 0][SECTION 2]...[SECTION n]
                                              //
tn+n   >>beam2>> [section 0][section 2]...[SECTION n]
```

If possible, it would enable cheaper displays, since processing wouldn't need complex etching, just highly timed laser diodes.

Comment: Lots of theory on this but no practical invention as far a Is know, maybe one could argue that quantum computing is a form.  An EM pulse puts an electron in a certain state and then after computation the state is read out later by another EM pulse.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect and optical phase conjugate reflection via degenerate 4 wave mixing http://cns-alumni.bu.edu/~slehar/PhaseConjugate/PhaseConjugate.html

Comment: will all your requisites it would be much simpler to have a laser fire at a fluorescent screen

Comment: @ManudeHanoi, that would require something out of the plane to hit the screen, making it larger.  The intention is to keep it as thin as possible.

Comment: ok I get it now !

Answer (score 2):

There are some very straightforward ways to use light to redirect light.  Any [photorefractive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photorefractive_effect) material can be exposed to an interference pattern between two sufficiently bright beams of coherent light to form a transient diffraction grating.  Another beam of light incident on the diffraction grating will be diffracted.  A diffraction grating can be recorded in [photochromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photochromic_lens) glass or plastic and used the same way.  In fact, light can be used to redirect light in any optically nonlinear material using that mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

-one could imagine that the 1st light is absorbed by the compound and the heat makes it expand and therefore change refractive index [as in patent US5037169](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5037169A/en?oq=%20US5037169)

-The heat could even induce a liquid to gas transition for a stronger effect [as in patent US6212308 (B1)](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=6212308&KC=&FT=E&locale=en_EP#)

source: [optical switch ,wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_switch)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to change the state of a material with a light beam which could be contrived to change the direction of another beam.

But may I offer another solution? Radiation pressure! Build an optomechanical switch, for which a strong laser beam moves a mirror through radiation pressure, thereby diverting the other beam. It’s not exactly a chemical, but it would get the job done, in principle!